# Can I get the compiled html of an Angular element?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-compile

I have compiled an element using the $compile service.  If I add that directly to the DOM, it looks great and all of the bindings are correct.  If I want that element as a string though, it shows `{{stuffHere}}` instead of the bindings.  Is there a way to get the html of the element after it's compiled?

```
$templateCache.put('template', '<div><div><div><span>content is {{content}}</span></div></div>   </div>');

$scope.content = 'Hello, World!';

var el = $compile($templateCache.get('template'))($scope);
$('body').append(el);

alert(el.html());
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/1sxvuyUZKbse862PieBa?p=preview

The element appended to the body shows `content is Hello, World!`

The alert shows `<div><div><span ng-binding>{{content}}</span></div></div>`

What I would like to see out of the alert is `<div><div><span ng-binding>Hello World</span></div></div>`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue is you're reading the contents of the element too early. If you add a `$timeout` to your read it will be correct:

```
angular.module('demo', []);
angular.module('demo').controller('PopoverDemoCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $compile, $templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('template', '<div><div><div><span>content is {{content}}</span></div></div></div>');

  $scope.content = 'Hello, World!';

  var el = $compile($templateCache.get('template'))($scope);
  $('body').append(el);
  $timeout(function() {
    console.log(el.html());
  }, 300);   // wait for a short while
});
```

[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/V0JypShYcPBeOgs7CaiD?p=preview)

### Why is `$timeout` required?

After the `$compile` method is called it will not immediately take effect. This is due to the `$digest` cycle, since it uses the `$scope` it needs to run the `$digest` cycle to see if anything has affected `$scope.content`. This is why you have to set a `$timeout`, you need to wait until the `$digest` cycle completes before the element's content actually gets changed. You can read a bit more about how this all ties together [here](http://www.toptal.com/angular-js/angular-js-demystifying-directives).

Comment: I am needing your help. I want the data after binding, too. but i still get {{ xxxx.xxx }} in ng-repeat. any solutions?

Comment: @chournsolidet Can you clarify? I'm unsure what you mean.

Comment: i have my template by getting from view.
var table = document.getElementById('my-table').outerHTML;

$templateCache.put('template', table);
and i put everything like the answer above. 
The point is that when i have ng-repeat to loop my td of my table already in the view. then i just get my table by id. it doesn't give me the rendered table but with {{ xxxx.xxxx }} instead.

Comment: by running your code, i still get this 
" <div><div><span class="ng-binding">content is {{content}}</span></div></div> " in console log.
All i want is " <div><div><span class="ng-binding">content is Hello, World! </span></div></div> " in console log