# Print Angular processed HTML

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to print a `div` that has been rendered using Angular. I'm using this answer as a starting point https://stackoverflow.com/a/30765875/285190, with the print function being pretty simple

```
$scope.printIt = function(){
   var table = document.getElementById('printArea').innerHTML;
   var myWindow = $window.open('', '', 'width=800, height=600');
   myWindow.document.write(table);
   myWindow.print();
};
```

The problem is the `innerHTML` contains all the items that would exist if the `ng-show` `ng-hide` directives hadn't been executed.

Is there a way to get the actual HTML the client is seeing, i.e. after Angular has performed its magic?

Answer (score 1):

Please use $compile service to transform angularized HTML to actual HTML.

Demonstration of $compile
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26660649/5317329

```
$scope.printIt = function () {
    angular.element('#tempHtml').html("");
    var table = document.getElementById('printArea').html();
    var compiledHTML = $compile(table)($scope);
        $timeout(function () {
            angular.element(document.querySelector('#tempHtml')).append(compiledHTML);//Please added <div id="tempHtml"></div> in page/View for temporary storage, Clear the div after print.
            console.log(angular.element('#tempHtml').html());
            var myWindow = $window.open('', '', 'width=800, height=600');
            myWindow.document.write(angular.element('#tempHtml').html());
            myWindow.print();
            angular.element('#tempHtml').html("");//Clearing the html
        }, 300);  // wait for a short while,Until all scope data is loaded If any complex one
};
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the right direction of `$compile`, but I didn't use it in the end. I ended up having a string template to compile, which also meant I didn't need the `tempHtml`